# Applying an operation efficiently on one column that depends on another column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe called `df` with around 20m rows, that looks like

```
userId  movieId rating
0   1   296     5.0
1   1   306     3.5
2   1   307     5.0
3   2   665     5.0
4   2   899     3.5
...
```

and I have a Series, `user_bias`

```
userId
1         0.280431
2         0.096580
3         0.163554
4        -0.155755
5         0.218621
...
```

I would like to subtract the matching value according to `userId` column in `user_bias` from `df['rating']`. For example the rating value of the first row should be replaced with `5.0 - 0.280431 = 4.719569`. I tried two solutions but they seems to be very slow. Is there a better way to achieve this?

### Solution 1

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'rating'] -= user_bias[row.userId]
```

### Solution 2

To get rid of the for loop, I've used `apply` method. Not sure if it is correct result-wise but it is again way slower than I expected.

`df['rating'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.rating - user_bias[row.userId], axis=1)`

Comment: Did you try merging the two and subtract the values in the merged df? It should be faster than the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
df['rating'] = df['rating'] - user_bias.reindex(df['userId']).values
```